# How can i call variables in my custompainter class and used it in my main

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, custom-painter

I have 2 variables ( midX and midY which are the middle point position of the x and y axis) in the custom painter class that i want to call from my main program to do something with the variables value(e.g. printing the values) Methods that I have tried is using static in Custompainter, however i get the error msg that i cant have static modifier in here. Is there other alternatives for this. Thanks in advance!

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  home: Builder(
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.grey,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                child: LayoutBuilder(
                    builder: (_, constraints) => Container(
                          width: constraints.widthConstraints().maxWidth,
                          height: constraints.heightConstraints().maxHeight,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Stack(children: [
                            // plotting X Y axis
                            Container(
                                width:
                                    constraints.widthConstraints().maxWidth,
                                height: constraints
                                    .heightConstraints()
                                    .maxHeight,
                                child: CustomPaint(painter: PlotPainter())),
                          ]),
                        )),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                child: Column(children: [
                  //Text("mid pixel value for x axis:$midX"),
                  //Text("mid pixel value for y axis:$midY"),
                ]),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Painter

```dart
class PlotPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final a_Length = size.width / 12;
    final midY = size.height / 2;
    final midX = size.width / 2;

    final paint = Paint()
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..strokeWidth = 1.8;

    final dottedline = Paint()
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.square
      ..strokeWidth = 1
      ..color = Colors.greenAccent;
    final textPainterx = TextPainter(
        text: const TextSpan(
          text: 'x',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 15,
          ),
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center);
    final textPaintery = TextPainter(
        text: const TextSpan(
          text: 'y',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 13,
          ),
        ),
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center);

    // X axis
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, midY), Offset(size.width, midY), paint);
    //y Axis
    canvas.drawLine(Offset(midX, 0), Offset(midX, size.height), paint);
    textPainterx.layout();
    textPaintery.layout();
    // Draw the text  X at the X axis
    textPainterx.paint(canvas, Offset(size.width - 7, midY + 1));
    // Draw the text  y at the Y axis
    textPaintery.paint(canvas, Offset(midX + 5, 0));
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead of code-image, CustomPainter size depends on parent widget, so you can grab value from usecase. instead of getting from painter class.

Comment: hmm i getting a message that say my post is mostly code. i would try to reduce it and post it. sorry for the inconvience caused

Comment: try to add more details, More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Hi sorry for the wait i have added the code snippet

Comment: Are you trying to put widget over paint?

Answer (score 0):

Bro, You are defining the variable `midY` and `midX` inside a function in a class. That is why you couldn't access it. Move it outside the function and use it in a class to access it using object of a class. Like this ->

```
class Painter {
 var midY;
 void paint() {
  midY = size/2;
 }
}
```

and use midY outside like this

```
print(Painter().midY);
```

Comment: i am still relatively new to flutter and dont quite get how can i achieve that as midX and midY depends on the size from the parent widget( constraints.widthConstraints().maxWidth and constraints.heightConstraints().maxHeight)

Comment: Hope the edit helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this,

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Exploration!',
      theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey),
      home: Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({super.key});

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (_, constraints) {
          final paintWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
          final paintHeight = constraints.maxHeight;

          final midX = paintWidth / 2;
          final midY = paintHeight / 2;
          return Container(
            width: constraints.widthConstraints().maxWidth,
            height: constraints.heightConstraints().maxHeight,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                // plotting X Y axis
                SizedBox(
                  width: paintWidth,
                  height: paintHeight,
                  child: CustomPaint(
                    painter: PlotPainter(),
                  ),
                ),

                SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text("mid pixel value for x axis:$midX"),
                      Text("mid pixel value for y axis:$midY"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also check with wrapping `Positioned` widget for Stack children.